# How to use Specific URLs for some posts

Tags: permalinks, page-specific-settings

I'm using the below format for permalinks in my blog:

`example.com/post-name`

Now I need to host a giveaway on the same blog and want to make a permalink structure like this:

`example.com/giveaways/post-name`

I don't want to use categories or tags in all my post URLs. Is there any way I can do that without errors?

Comment: you could either by the .htaccess as well

Answer (score 1):

You need to add a `Custom Post Type` with slug `giveaways` and create posts under that Post Type. It will give you url like `example.com/giveaways/post-name` as required.